# Non-public API usage On IOS App Store with Unity 2017

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

After uploading the project on the IOS App store, I received an email from the store team

It says:

> Non-public API usage: The app references non-public symbols in
>   (project name):
>   __ZN10ClipperLib11ClipperBase7AddPathERKNSt3__16vectorINS_8IntPointENS1_9allocatorIS3_EEEENS_8PolyTypeEb,
>   __ZN10ClipperLib7Clipper7ExecuteENS_8ClipTypeERNSt3__16vectorINS3_INS_8IntPointENS2_9allocatorIS4_EEEENS5_IS7_EEEENS_12PolyFillTypeESB_,
>   __ZN10ClipperLib7ClipperC1Ei, __ZN10ClipperLib7ClipperD1Ev

- The Project is build with UNITY 2017(it has few thrd party plugins/libs imported)
- Could not find any text "__ZN10ClipperLib..... in the project

I think some thirdparty plugin imported in the project is causing the issues, but I am unable to identify the exact library.

Has anybody come across this issue before. If so could you identify which plugin was causing the issues?

Comment: I would say it's some variant of http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php. Do you have anything like that in your project?